# Taylor series of a function of several functions

Tags: taylor-expansion

How do we find the Taylor series of $f(c,\nabla c,\nabla^{2}c)$ where $c,\nabla c$ and $\nabla^{2}c$ are functions of $x$ in $1$-D.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uz9N.png)

Comment: What could the Taylor series of a triplet be?

Comment: @copper.hat i've inserted a pic from the answer written in a paper for Cahn and Hilliard

Comment: I suspect that is just the first order approximation of $f$ evaluated at the above point, with an inglorious abuse of notation. (What is Cahn and Hilliard?)

Comment: @copper.hat i'm reading mathematical biology book for Murray James Volume 1 section 11.6 that models diffusion problems.One of them is a diffusion equation of cell density n(x,t) with a flux being proportional to the gradient of a potential.I have an energy functional which is the integral of all  the energy density over a volume.They expand it in taylor series but they didn't write the steps.The final answer includes a Laplacian gradient and a squared gradient of n(x,t).They put as reference many papers , one of them is that of Cahn and Hilliard.